# DateTime.Date (long value)

Tags: vb.net, date, datetime, basic4android

I have spent quite a few hours and still unable to understand this:

```
Dim unix_time_at_midnight As Long
DateTime.DateFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy"   
unix_time_at_midnight = DateTime.DateParse(DateTime.Date(unix_time*1000))/1000
```

where both unix_time_at_midnight and unix_time are long values. I understand `DateTime.DateParse` excepts a String and converts it to DateTime. What is `(DateTime.Date(unix_time*1000))/1000` returning and what is its equivalent in Java? The requirement is to get the number of seconds since GMT midnight and I have successfully implemented it in Java. However, I would like to understand this particular line of code written in VB.net

EDIT: This method was written in [Basic4Android](http://www.basic4ppc.com/android/wiki/index.php/DateTime) and probably constitutes more of its libraries then [vb.net](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.datetime_methods%28v=vs.80%29.aspx). However, I have looked into each for details but unable to understand. Would appreciate if you could elaborate. Please see the links.

Comment: Looks like an extension method. The `Date` property on `DateTime` is read only.

Comment: In that case, it probably expects a number in milliseconds.

Comment: Yes, @MrLister - but that also means that there is no way we can tell what it actually does. Sarah - you will need to look into the source code of the extension method yourself. Perhaps post it here if you don't understand it.

Comment: @Oded I have edited my question based on your comments, does it help?

Comment: @Sarah - What don't you understand? The documentation in the page you linked to for `Basic4Android` for this method seems to explain what it does.

Comment: @Oded I don't understand what does this return: (DateTime.Date(unix_time*1000))/1000 considering DateTime.DateParse accepts a string value while unit_time is long and is DateTime.DateParse equivalent to Date in java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take this:

```
DateTime.Date(unix_time*1000)
```

The documentation says:

> **Date (Ticks As Long) As String**
>
> Returns a string representation of the date (which is stored as ticks).
>   The date format can be set with the DateFormat keyword.

So that part returns a *string* representing the date.

It then uses `DateTime.DateParse`, which is documented as:

> **DateParse (Date As String) As Long**
>
> Parses the given date string and returns its ticks representation.

---

Taken together, this appears to take the ticks, multiplied by 1000, converted to a string that doesn't contain hour information which is parsed back to ticks which are divided by 1000.

The important thing to note is that the `DateFormat` set on the line before contains only the formatting for the date, no hours/minutes/seconds and smaller units of time exist in it. This means that the string returned essentially represents midnight of that date.

Comment: I am sorry for the continuous questions but if the string returned is the midnight of a date, then unix_time_at_midnight which is a long value represents what? What is DateTime.Date(unix_time*1000) in java?

Comment: @Sarah - [Unix time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) is measured in seconds from midnight, January 1st, 1970. That's what the `ticks` represent. What is it in Java? I though you were asking about VB.NET? It would be similar and I believe JodaTime can handle Unix epoch ticks.